# Not showing Design tab in borland C++ builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder-2007

Not showing "Design" tab, while loading the .cpp file in Borland C++ Builder. I have three the extension files like `.cpp, .dfm and .h`. I'm using Borland C++ Builder 2007. please provide me a work around for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure all three files have the same base name, eg: `Unit1.cpp`, `Unit1.h`, and `Unit1.dfm`.

Make sure the .h file has a proper header guard that conforms to Borland's naming convention, eg:

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
...
#endif
```

Make sure the .cpp file contais a `#pragma resource "*.dfm"` statement.